# #include file (file not found) in AS2

Tags: actionscript-2

It has been many years since i played around with AS2 and can't seem to find anything online.

if i use this code in the IDE

```
#include "test.as"

testFunction();
```

Where is test.as supposed to live? It doesn't find it in the same directory of the FLA, and I tried setting the ActionScript settings, but that didn't work either.

**RESOLVED**

issue was due to how my user account was set up on OSX. My user was set up as DOMAIN\user and some software doesn't like "\" I've had the same issue with Unity3d.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#include "test.as"
```

would be in the same level directory as your fla
http://bit.ly/xFqsC8

Comment: thanks, it was actually an issue with how my user account was set up on my work machine that was causing an issue for some reason.  I knew it had to be something silly like that.  My user was set up as DOMAIN\user and some software doesn't like "\" I've had the same issue with Unity3d.  Thanks anyway, i appreciate it.